# How do i get count of records for each month in an array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a clients table where I am trying to get data count for each months (using the created_at column). The selected year variable below ($selectedYear) is coming from a form request to select which year to display.

```
public function clientsCount(Request $request)
{
    $selectedYear = $request->selectedYear ?? now()->format('Y');

    $orderedMonthsData = [
        1 => "January ". $selectedYear,
        2 => "February ". $selectedYear,
        3 => "March ". $selectedYear,
        4 => "April ". $selectedYear,
        5 => "May ". $selectedYear,
        6 => "June ". $selectedYear,
        7 => "July ". $selectedYear,
        8 => "August ". $selectedYear,
        9 => "September ". $selectedYear,
        10 => "October ". $selectedYear,
        11 => "November ". $selectedYear,
        12 => "December ". $selectedYear
    ];

    $clientYear = Client::query()->whereYear('created_at', $selectedYear);

    $orderedClientsData = [
        1 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 1)->count(),
        2 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 2)->count(),
        3 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 3)->count(),
        4 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 4)->count(),
        5 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 5)->count(),
        6 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 6)->count(),
        7 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 7)->count(),
        8 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 8)->count(),
        9 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 9)->count(),
        10 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 10)->count(),
        11 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 11)->count(),
        12 => $clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 12)->count(),
    ];

    dd($orderedMonthsData, $orderedClientsData);
}
```

when i die dump it, this is the result.

[image: when i die dump it, this is the result.]

It worked perfectly for the first array ($orderedMonthsData) but the second array ($orderedClientsData) is not working perfectly. I have records in other months which means their count is not supposed to be 0. In the second result, It means i am only getting result for the first item in the array. how can i query it so that i will get the count for other months too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve data only once from the database

```
public function clientsCount(Request $request)
{
    $selectedYear = $request->selectedYear ?? now()->format('Y');

    $data = Client::selectRaw('count(id) as count, month(created_at) as month')
        ->whereYear('created_at', $selectedYear)
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->pluck('count', 'month');

    $period = CarbonPeriod::create(
        now()->setYear($selectedYear)->startOfYear(), '1 month', now()->setYear($selectedYear)->endOfYear()
    );

    $orderedMonthsData = [];

    foreach ($period as $key => $date) {
        $orderedMonthsData[++$key] = $date->format('F Y');
    }

    $orderedClientsData = [];

    foreach ($orderedMonthsData as $month => $text) {
        $orderedClientsData[$month] = $data->get($month) ?? 0;
    }

    // dd($orderedMonthsData, $orderedClientsData);
}
```

You don't have to create `orderedMonthsData` manually. You can make it with a code what I provided above for you.

Answer (score 0):

[This is NOT a solution, but I need some space to answer you.]

I don't think anybody can say why all your function calls return 0, except the first.

For example:

```
$clientYear->whereMonth('created_at', 2)
```

appears to return 0 records, but you claim it should return a higher number.

My advise would be to first use normal SQL without the frameworking and see how many records return when querying the right table, using the year 2019 and the month 2.

Work your way up from there through eloquent en laravel.

Answer (score 0):

try this One

```
public function clientsCount(Request $request)
    {
        $selectedYear = $request->selectedYear ?? now()->format('Y');

        $clientsJoinedInYear = Client::query()
            ->whereYear('created_at', $selectedYear)
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y") as date_of_joining_month_and_year ,count(*) as no_of_joined_clients')
            ->groupBy('date_of_joining_month_and_year')
            ->pluck('no_of_joined_clients', 'date_of_joining_month_and_year');

        dd($clientsJoinedInYear);
    }
```

This will give you the exact result that you are looking for.

> And DON'T EVER PASS ANY INPUT FROM END USER INTO `SELECTRAW`
> FUNCTION